# Raid0 recovery - failed mobo

Tags: windows-7, linux, data-recovery, software-raid, raid-0

Short story: motherboard died, need to recover data from 2 working HDD's in RAID0

Long story: My mobo died on a Dell Studio XPS 7100, I basically upgraded all the components and my pc is now up and running. However I need to recover data from my two old HDDs.

These were set up in what I assume was RAID0 by Dell (I also assume software RAID, there was no raid controller card plugged in the motherboard). The pc was ordered from Dell and came with the OS installed and everything, at the time I did not know a thing about computers (hey I was still going to school) and certainly did not know what RAID was. Anyway everything, including the OS was on the RAID... And since I didn't even know it was a RAID or how that worked I didn't back everything up. Guess now I know better but its a little too late.

The drives themselves are working without problems.

Anyway after some research I now installed Linux Ubuntu 14.04.2 on an external HDD, booted my pc up from it and tried to use the sudo mdadm commands.

The two drives are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb each 1Tb WD drives connected thru SATA cables to my motherboard

The first one of the two, /dev/sda is also partitioned in 3 parts: a "Dell Utility" partition, the two others are "promise_fasttrack_raid_member"

I tried some command lines and they did not quite work out:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

sudo mdadm -Q /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3: is not an md array

sudo mdadm -Q /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: is not an md array
```

For now I'm waiting for my new SSD and HDD to arrive, and I'm going to start reinstalling windows and everything on those. However I would still like to recover the data from my old drives.

Any help would be really appreciated. :/

Oh and my current pc specs (not from the old dell, but my new setup)

- Motherboard: MSI Z97 gaming 7
- CPU: Intel i7 4770K
- PSU: Corsair RM750
- RAM: 2x DIMM 8GB DDR3 1866
- video card: Asus R9 290 DC2OC 4Gb GDDR5
- The two old harddrives: 2x 1Tb WDC WD10EALX-759BA1

Comment: Your are on the right track, but no all software RAID are equal. I suspect that dell used intel fake RAID. Under Linux that translates to the dm driver. Not to md. (which is why md does not find any md raid).